# second imageview not displaying anything

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a problem displaying two images (software generated) at the same time.

Here is the xml snippet for the layout containing the imageviews.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#005400"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/output_img1" 
        android:contentDescription="First image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/output_img2" 
        android:contentDescription="Second Image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the snippet where i create the objects to address the imageviews (in the `onCreateView` of the `Fragment` containing the imageviews:

```
outImage1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.output_img1);
outImage1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
outImage2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.output_img2);
outImage2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

Here is the function that displays the image (scaling it) in the first imageview (this works, and is part of the code for the `Fragment` containing the imageviews):

```
public void displayOutImg(Bitmap map){
    int bitmapWidth = map.getWidth();
    int bitmapHeight = map.getHeight();
    int widthParent = outImage1.getWidth();      
    int heightParent = outImage1.getHeight();
    float density = DisplayContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float xScale = ((float) widthParent * density) / bitmapWidth; 
    float yScale = ((float) heightParent * density) / bitmapHeight;
    float minScale = (xScale<yScale)?xScale:yScale;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(minScale, minScale);
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(map, 0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, matrix, true);
    outImage1.setImageBitmap(scaled);
}
```

Here is the function to display the image in the second imageview (this seems to do nothing, and is also in the code of the `Fragment` containing the imageviews):

```
public void displayOutImg2(Bitmap map){
    int bitmapWidth = map.getWidth();
    int bitmapHeight = map.getHeight();
    int widthParent = outImage2.getWidth();      
    int heightParent = outImage2.getHeight();
    float density = DisplayContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float xScale = ((float) widthParent * density) / bitmapWidth; 
    float yScale = ((float) heightParent * density) / bitmapHeight;
    float minScale = (xScale<yScale)?xScale:yScale;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(minScale, minScale);
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(map, 0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, matrix, true);
    outImage2.setImageBitmap(scaled);
}
```

I am trying to display side by side the images resulting from two different processing methods on the same data, but only the first one shows. I thought it might be a problem with the results of the second method, but even if I pass the results of the first one to the `displayOutImg2()` nothing shows in the second imageview.
I also tried to see if perhaps I was calling the second function from somewhere in my code that could not access the GUI for some reason. So I called it right after the first one (as in, the line below), to no avail. The functions are called from my main activity, like so (`images` is the Fragment that contains the imageviews):

```
public void drawFirst(Bitmap result){
    images.displayOutImg1(result);
    delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
}
public void drawSecond(Bitmap result){
    images.displayOutImg2(result);
    delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
}
```

My googling failed me so far, and I was not able to find a solution to this issure, which appears to me should be something rather basic. I am sorry if this is something obvious but I have been programming in java for android only for the past couple weeks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the image actually not behind the other imageview?? To display views over each other you must use FrameLayout for that. Or just use canvas with paint to draw two images over each other.

Comment: Could you give more details?
I am not trying to display views over each other, but rather side by side.

Comment: Then you just need to use linearlayout horizontal and add two imageviews inside of it with wrap_content width and match_parent height. Instead of using the relativelayout which is useless in ur case.

Comment: width=wrap_content does not work for my case because I need to resize the bitmaps when i display them. See either `displayOutImg` or `displayOutImg2`. In either case, with wrap_content I get widthParent = 0, which messes everything up